# What are the differences between geology, petrology, and lithology?

Tags: geology, petrology

What differences are there between  geology, petrology, and lithology?

If I were to get into any of those fields, what exactly would I be studying?

Also, are petrology and lithology just branches of geology?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The basic differences are:

**Geology**

1. study of rocks and minerals: the study of the structure of the Earth or another planet, especially its rocks, soil, and minerals, and its history and origins
2. structure of area: the rocks, minerals, and physical structure of a specific area

**Petrology**

1. study of rocks: the study of sedimentary, igneous, and metamorphic rocks with respect to their occurrence, structure, origin, history, and mineral content

**Lithology**

1. description of the physical characteristics of a rock unit or rock formation, and actually not a scientific discipline as the two above

Comment: Lithology refers to a type of rock or a rock unit (I never heard that it is a scientific branch).

Comment: Yes, Lithology is a scientific study, and considered as a separate branch of geology.

Comment: My English is once again worse than I thought: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lithology

Comment: @Spießbürger - It's not your english.  I've never heard "lithology" referred to as a branch of geology.  Someone who studies the details of lithology calls themselves a "petrologist", not a "lithologist".

Comment: @Joe Kington It might be a really old definition, because OED also has it: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/109165?redirectedFrom=lithology#eid

Comment: I'm with Joe — I've never heard "lithology" used that way. I suggest editing the answer.

Comment: edited for preference of more recent definitions.

Comment: I'd like to add that "petrologists" are usually considered to be scientists dealing with igneous and metamorphic rocks. If they are "sedimentary petrologists" there are usually just "sedimentologists".

Comment: Lithology is not a branch of geology, but a method for descriptive definition of rocks. Using petrology you would assign a rock a lithology description and name.